# Bootstrap Dynamic form working but not inserting data into database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on Bootstrap Dynamic form. But data is not inserting into database. Emp_id is employee id. leave_id is employee's current leave id fetched from other table. Both emp_id & leave_id will be same for every data insertion.

please help me to solve this problem.
 Thanks in advance.

> HTML

```
<!--Alernative Staff Starts-->
<form id="alernativeForm" name="alernativeForm" role="form" data-leave-id="'.$leaves['id'].'">
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <td><strong>Day</strong></td>
           <td><strong>Period</strong></td>
           <td><strong>Name of alernate Teacher/Staff</strong></td>
           <td><strong>Add More or Delete</strong></td>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="add_name" name="add_name">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control day_list" name="day[]" id="day" placeholder="Day"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control period_list" name="period[]" id="period" placeholder="Period"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control teacher_list" name="teacher[]" id="teacher" placeholder="Name of alernate Teacher/Staff"></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-primary" name="add" id="add" role="button">Add More</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<!--Alernative Staff Ends-->
```

> My jQuery & AJAX

```
/*Dynamic Field Starts*/

            var i = 1;
            $("#add").click(function(){
                    i++;
        $("#dynamic_field").append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" class="form-control day_list" name="day[]" id="day" placeholder="Day"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control period_list" name="period[]" id="period" placeholder="Period"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control teacher_list" name="teacher[]" id="teacher" placeholder="Name of alernate Teacher/Staff"></td><td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-remove" name="remove" id="'+i+'" role="button">X</a></td></tr>')
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(){
                var btn_remove_id = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#row'+btn_remove_id+'').remove();
            });

          $("#alernativeSubmit").click(function(){
           var dynamic_field = $("#alernativeForm").serialize();
           var leave_id = $('#alernativeForm').attr('data-leave-id');
           var emp_id = <?php echo $userRow['emp_id'];?>; 
           alert($('#alernativeForm').serialize() + "&emp_id=" + emp_id + "&leave_id=" + leave_id)
           $.ajax({  
            url:"core/name.php",  
            method:"POST", 
             cache: false, 
            data: $('#alernativeForm').serialize() + "&emp_id=" + emp_id + "&leave_id=" + leave_id,  
            success:function(data)  
            {  
                alert(data)
                 $('#alernativeForm')[0].reset();
                  $('#alernateStaff').modal('hide');

            }  
       });  

       });
   /*Dynamic Field Ends*/
```

> PHP

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';

     $day_number = count($_POST['day']);  
     $period_number = count($_POST['period']);  
     $teacher_number = count($_POST['teacher']); 
     $emp_id = $_POST['emp_id'];
     $leave_id = $_POST['leave_id'];


     if($day_number > 0)  
     {  
          for($i=0; $i<$day_number; $i++)  
          {  
               if(trim($_POST["day"][$i] != '') && trim($_POST["period"][$i] != '') && trim($_POST["teacher"][$i] != '') && trim($_POST["emp_id"] != '') && trim($_POST["leave_id"] != ''))  
               {  
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO alernate(`emp_id`,`leave_id`,`day`,`period`,`teacher`) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["emp_id"])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["leave_id"])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["day"][$i])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["period"][$i])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["teacher"][$i])."')");  
                          echo "Data Inserted";  
               }  
          }  

     }  


    ?>
```

Comment: what errors you see in console?

Comment: I think it is logical error

Comment: Data Inserted msg showing but no insertion

Comment: mysql_query is depreciated you should be using PDO or mysqli_*. Also look in to parameter binding in your query for added protection.

Comment: @nerdlyist I am using php 5.5

Comment: Try echoing some variables in your PHP, just before the mysql insert query. To see if the data actually gets passed to the function and to the file.

Comment: I think Nerdlyist is correct, you can try PDO or mysqli, also you need to check, affected rows before sending the message "Data Inserted"

Comment: @LuukSkeur  I echoed out all the values `echo $_POST["emp_id"];
            echo $_POST["leave_id"];
            echo $_POST["day"][$i];
            echo $_POST["period"][$i];
            echo $_POST["teacher"][$i];` every works perfect but not inserting in to data base. But I can insert into other tables by using MySQL_ perfectly.

Comment: @MarmikBhatt `MySQL_` works perfect in other modules of the project like signup, add leave and ,many more.

Comment: I Got answer to my question I have written wrong spelling of my table name **alernate**. Actually it's **alternate**